# FireFox 3.6 - 9 drops favicon when changing window.location

Tags: javascript, firefox, favicon

[Problem](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=519028) exists only on FireFox (from 3.6 up to current 9), other browsers are fine. My code looks like this:

```
jQuery.extend({
    AnchorFromUrl : function(url) {
        var anchor = url.substr(1).replace('.html','');
        $.fizzer_anchor = anchor;
        window.location.hash = anchor;
        return anchor;
    }
});
```

The most weird thing is that if I place an alert before the window.location.hash = anchor; line, after clicking Ok favicon doesn't disappear, remove that alert() and you get your favicon disappearing.

Note: it also drops the favicon if you just do `window.location = something`.

Comment: Just to add the info also here: It is a bug that has been reported here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=519028

Comment: still exists as of FF 44

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I noticed this behaviour, too. Every now and then Firefox drops a favicon or it refuses to put the favicon alongside my bookmark. I think this is a Firefox bug.

To workaround this (and for other functionality), I installed the [Favicon Picker add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7849). Of course, this doesn't solve your problem on other computers, like clients and the like.

Comment: yes, it is a [firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=519028). This is not an answer. @Phisius I wonder why this was accepted, the other answer should be.

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem, but found this interesting post and it worked for me, its just adding 2 lines of javascript.
The problem occure when the hash element changes, so, we need to re-stablish it via javascript

http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/javascript/the-case-of-the-disappearing-favicon/

this is the code

```
function setFavicon() {
  var link = $('link[type="image/x-icon"]').remove().attr("href");
  $('<link href="'+ link +'" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />').appendTo('head');
}
```

Or (thanks to Mottie) using jQuery detach

```
$('link[type*=icon]').detach().appendTo('head');
```

Comment: my version of jQuery (1.6.4) doesnt seem to support the type=image/x-icon syntax, so I changed it to type*=icon. Any better suggestions?

Comment: @Mansiemans, try to use quotes for the attribute value: `$("link[type='image/x-icon']")`

Comment: A more generally applicable selector would be `$('link[rel~="icon"]')`.

Comment: I'm still having this problem in Firefox 14.0.1 and I've found that `detach()` works just as nicely: `$('link[type*=icon]').detach().appendTo('head');`

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me :

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.type = 'image/x-icon';
link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
link.href = 'FAV_ICON_URL';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Refer : [Changing Website Icon Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/260876/644011)