# Favicon not displaying in FireFox

Tags: java, javascript, html, favicon

Favicon loads fine in all browsers including FireFox.
I am getting a problem only with those pages which are ending with # sign.
If I hit URL "http://localhost/app/index.jsp" in FF then Favicon loads properly, but when I am going to any other page from menu using link like "http://localhost/app/login.jsp#" then the Favicon does not display in Tab or URLbar.

This problem is only in FF when the URL ends with a # sign.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Can you add some code or describe how you are setting the favicon?

Comment: You should not be using empty hash links. That is bad ju-ju. Use something like `<a href="javascript:void();">Test</a>` instead of `<a href="#">Test</a>`. The latter is a bad practice. As you've already seen, empty hash links cause a variety of subtle issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FireFox 3.6 - 9 drops favicon when changing window.location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409759/firefox-3-6-9-drops-favicon-when-changing-window-location)

Answer (score 2):

This is a known Firefox bug:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=519028