# Browser displayed favicon blinks on hash change

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-closure-library

When I change the hash location via document.location.hash or window.location.hash, most browsers have some form of a 'blinking' effect. I need to prevent that, as I am implementing a history plugin based on hash changes and the 'blinking' effect is just plain ugly. I know it is do-able as I have seen many Ajax based products with this(loads from Google especially)

This is the code used to display the favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.mysite.com/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FireFox 3.6 - 9 drops favicon when changing window.location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409759/firefox-3-6-9-drops-favicon-when-changing-window-location)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this previous answer to a similar question and see if it works for you:

[FireFox 3.6 - 9 drops favicon when changing window.location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409759/firefox-3-6-9-drops-favicon-when-changing-window-location/4630726#4630726)