# How does GMAIL have a favicon that shows an unread message count?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, webkit, gmail

GMAIL in chrome has a favicon that shows an unread message count. Does anyone know how they do  that? Is that them changing images? Or is there a property that allows you to set the number near the favicon?

Thanks

Comment: This is not how gmail does it, but this is how I was able to mock it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964144/dynamically-generated-favicon/6964230#6964230

Answer (score 7):

I am not 100% certain on how Google accomplishes this however, someone created a UserScript to mimic the functionality. You can view the source code of this script and see how they accomplished it.

<s>http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/39432</s>

**EDIT**

I'm including this resource since userscripts is no longer around:

http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/

on github

https://github.com/ejci/favico.js

Comment: This is the answer for How does GMAIL have a favicon that shows an unread message count?

Answer (score 5):

They use different images for counter icons, They have one default favicon and use javascript to update as new email arrives.

e.g.

1. <s>https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/images/2/unreadcountfavicon/0.png</s>
2. <s>https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/images/2/unreadcountfavicon/1.png</s>
3. <s>https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/images/2/unreadcountfavicon/2.png</s>
4. <s>https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/images/2/unreadcountfavicon/3.png</s>

   [image: 6]

<s>https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/images/2/unreadcountfavicon/n.png</s>

Answer (score 1):

There's no property that sets a number next to the favicon, but you can change it in javascript. Check out this question
[Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically/260876#260876)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how *Google* did it, but the way I did it way:

```
 $('body').append($('<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="http://localhost/myfavicon.ico"/>'))
```

As needed.

Answer (score -1):

I have no clue how they do it, but there's no reason you can't have your /faveicon.ico be responded to by a dynamic server-side script which generates/provides certain content based on information of the user in question.

That said... I don't think most browsers would get the updated Faveicon usually, as most seem to only check it once per session.