# after appending inline html to html the window.open() doesn't shows append data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here i created

After appending inline html table data  to html table, open to new tab and show print view

but the problem was appending data is not shows.

There only show html page table data

test.html

```
<div>
    <p>Your content here</p>
    <table  id="toPrint">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

print button in another html page and onclick by using backbone.js

```
print : function() {
    var htmlTable2 = '<tr class="header">'
        + '<td>Prasanth</td>' + '<td>12345678</td>'
        + '</tr>';
    var html1 = $("#toPrint tbody").append(htmlTable2);
    window.open("test.html").print();
},
```

how this change to html page table + append  inline html data to open a new tab and show print option.

Comment: what is `test.html`? another page? or the same page? if it is the same page, it will be reloaded and your appended row is obviously lost. if it is another page, then obviously the entire table isn't there.

Comment: @abhitalks test.html is another page

Comment: @abhitalks what was really happens in there? please share it here. its a request

Comment: You are making changes in one page and then opening another page in a popup! How do you expect that page to reflect the changes you made in earlier page?

Comment: @abhitalks then how to open that changed page ?

Comment: @abhitalks is it possible to open the changed page in another way?

Comment: A little searching could lead you to solutions. Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19139052/1355315

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `window.open("test.html").print();` do `window.print();`

By opening your page again, you lose the changes.