# Badges For Buttons using html and CSS

Tags: html, css

Hello everyone I am trying to do something like this

[image]

I need it for buttons

so far I tried it using SVG and buttons something like this

```
<div style="position:relative;">
        <div style="border-radius:50px;background-color:#F3B200;border:2px solid;width:35px;height:35px;position:absolute;left:84%;margin-top:-18px;">
        <center>5</center>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="width:170px;">
            <center> MYbutton</center>
         </button>
         </div>
         </div>
```

But this does not work in a proper way. I need it to be responsive .

Comment: *"I need it to be responsive..."*: Meaning?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19139052/1355315

Comment: Responsive in the sense I am using twitter bootstrap I dont want the badge to move to another place when the screen size is changed

Comment: also is it possible to add more than one badge for a button?

Comment: why not? just follow the link I gave.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is probably the simplest way I can think of:

Give your button a custom `data` attribute. In this case I've used `data-count` (the `count` part could be anything you wish):

```
<button data-count="5"></button>
```

Use the value of the data attribute as the `content` of a `:before` pseudo element:

```
button:before {
    content: attr(data-count);
}
```

Full demo below....

```css
button {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(37,130,188,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 32%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 42%,rgba(175,224,234,1) 100%);
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

button:before {
    content: attr(data-count);
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgb(67, 151, 232);
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -7px;
}

button.badge-top-right:before {
    left: auto;
    right: -7px;
}

button.badge-bottom-right:before {
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    right: -7px;
    bottom: -7px;
}

button.badge-bottom-left:before {
    top: auto;
    bottom: -7px;
}
```

```html
<button data-count="5"></button>
<button data-count="5" class="badge-top-right"></button>
<button data-count="5" class="badge-bottom-right"></button>
<button data-count="5" class="badge-bottom-left"></button>
```

Comment: also is it possible to add more than one badge(data-count) for a button?

Comment: Yes. You can add multiple data attributes to any element. However, you are limited to two pseudo elements, `:before` and `:after`