# How to get badge value of button in Angular JS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want badge value of a  Button, this represent badge is `data-text-as-pseudo-element` i am new to angular so how do i get it ?

```
    <style 
    type="text/css">[data-text-as-pseudo-element]::before { content: attr(data-text-as-pseudo-element); }
    </style>


        <button role="tab" title="Chats" tabindex="0" aria-label="Chats, 1
           unread notification." aria-selected="true" style="position: relative;
           display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;
           overflow: hidden; align-items: center; justify-content: center;
           background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; text-align:
           left; border-width: 0px; width: 80px; padding-top: 2px; height: 50px;
           cursor: pointer; border-style: solid;">
    <div role="none"
           style="position: relative; display: flex; flex-direction: column;
           flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; overflow: hidden; align-items: center;
           justify-content: center; width: 80px; height: 50px;">
    <div
           aria-hidden="true" data-text-as-pseudo-element="" style="position:
           relative; display: inline; flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; overflow:
           hidden; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word; height:
           20px; font-size: 20px; color: rgb(0, 120, 212); background-color:
           rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-family: SkypeAssets-Light; padding: 0px;
           cursor: inherit;"></div><div data-text-as-pseudo-element="Chats"
           style="position: relative; display: inline; flex-grow: 0;
           flex-shrink: 0; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre; text-overflow:
           ellipsis; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(0, 120, 212); font-family:
           &quot;SF Regular&quot;, &quot;Segoe System UI Regular&quot;,
           &quot;Segoe UI Regular&quot;, sans-serif; font-weight: 400;
           text-align: center; margin-top: 2px; align-self: stretch; cursor:
           inherit;"></div><div role="none" aria-hidden="true" style="position:
           absolute; display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-grow: 0;
           flex-shrink: 0; overflow: visible; align-items: center; height: 24px;
           width: 30px; top: 0px; right: 12px; justify-content: center;">
    <div
           role="none" style="position: relative; display: flex; flex-direction:
           column; flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; overflow: hidden; align-items:
           center; justify-content: center; height: 20px; min-width: 20px;
           border-radius: 10px; background-color: rgb(244, 67, 54);
           padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px; width: 20px; border-color:
           rgb(240, 244, 248); border-width: 2px; border-style: solid;">
    <div
           data-text-as-pseudo-element="1" style="position: relative; display:
           inline; flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; overflow: hidden; white-space:
           pre; text-overflow: ellipsis; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size:
           10px; line-height: 10px; text-align: center; background-color:
           rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;SF Bold&quot;, &quot;Segoe
           System UI Bold&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Bold&quot;, sans-serif;
           font-weight: 400; cursor: inherit;">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </button>
```

[image: this]

Any suggestion ?

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: You can take this answer as a starting point, designing the button with badge itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27016902/1854269 . Then you can use ng-class directive to dynamically assign a class to the button, depends on whether there are some notifcations or not.
Unfortunately, the example above is not workng properly in IE 11, if this is important for you.

Comment: @CodeMonkey  ok but how do i get the value of chats count ?

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a working example. Unfortunately, this code is not working in IE11. To make it work in IE11, CSS has to be adjusted.

Example is based on solution from here:
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27016902/1854269)

The main point is that from example over the link: you indicate, how many notifcations do you have over the attribute 'data-count':

```
<button class="notification-button" data-count="5"></button>
```

To make it dynamic in angularjs, you have to bind this attribute with scope varialbe using ng-attr-* directive

```
<button class="notification-button" ng-attr-data-count="{{counter}}"></button>
```

[AngularJS docs gn-attr-*](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation)

[When to use ng-attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332561/when-to-use-ng-attr)

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

myCtrl.inject = ['$scope'];

function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.counter = 0;

  $scope.increment = function() {
    $scope.counter++;
  }
}
```

```css
.notification-button {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(37, 130, 188, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 32%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 42%, rgba(175, 224, 234, 1) 100%);
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.notification-button:before {
  content: attr(data-count);
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(67, 151, 232);
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -7px;
}

.notification-button.badge-top-right:before {
  left: auto;
  right: -7px;
}

.notification-button.badge-bottom-right:before {
  left: auto;
  top: auto;
  right: -7px;
  bottom: -7px;
}

.notification-button.badge-bottom-left:before {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button ng-click="increment();">Increment</button>

  <div>
    {{counter}}
  </div>

  <button class="notification-button" ng-attr-data-count="{{counter}}"></button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i don't want to create a button with badge i just want the how to get `chat` badge value 1 from the snippet that i provided in question.