# Change Value of Panini Front Matter with jQuery

Tags: handlebars.js, zurb-foundation-6

I have some Panini front matter like this:

---

### title: Page Title

...which I am inserting into my page like this:

## {{ title }}

How would I go about dynamically changing the value of "title" so that the page name would change? Can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a similar questions asked before in regards to dynamic page title change through jQuery. This might help you get to your solution:

[How to change the title of page through jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381403/how-to-change-the-title-of-page-through-jquery)

Comment: Thank you for responding.

My question probably wasn't as clear as it could be. I know how to change the H1 text programmatically. 

My question has to do with the page titles defined using front matter (see: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/panini.html#custom-data). I would like to see if there is a way to dynamically change the value of the front matter variables, in my case the "title" var.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't dynamic in the sense of changing after load, but maybe it accomplishes what you need.

In my layouts/default.html layout in the head I have

```
<title>{{ title }} | Site name</title>
```

And in the front matter of the page:

```
---
layout: default
title: Your title
---
```