# Best way to make title bounce when a new message is received and tab is inactive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

This is what I have so far, but it's ugly and feels non-best practicey. For example, if multiple messages are received, it starts the changeTitle cycle multiple times.

```
var hasFocus = true;
$(window).bind("blur", function() { 
    hasFocus = false;
});
$(window).bind("focus", function() {
    hasFocus = true;
    document.title = 'SiteName | Chat'; 
});
var i=0;
function changeTitle() {
    i++;
    if(i%2) {
        document.title = 'New message on SiteName!';
    }
    else {
        document.title = 'SiteName | Chat';
    }
    if(!hasFocus) {
        setTimeout('changeTitle()',1000);
    }
}

// Then I call changeTitle() when a new message is received.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing.

```
function changeTitle() {
    i++;
    if(i%2) {
        document.title = 'New message on mysite!';
    }
    else {
        document.title = 'MySite | Chat';
    }
    if(!hasFocus) {
        titleCurrentlyChanging = true;
        setTimeout('changeTitle()',1000);
    }
    else {
        titleCurrentlyChanging = false;
        i=0;
        document.title = 'MySite | Chat';
    }
}
```

Inside the addMessage() function, which is called when a new message is received:

```
if(!hasFocus && !titleCurrentlyChanging) {
    changeTitle();
}
```

Inside the global namespace:

```
var i = 0;
var titleCurrentlyChanging = false;

var hasFocus = true;
$(window).bind("blur", function() { 
    hasFocus = false;
});
$(window).bind("focus", function() {
    hasFocus = true;
    document.title = 'MySite | Chat'; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I can think of three:

1. The Better gReader add-on for Firefox actually changes the favicon of the tab to show unread posts. Have a look at this question: [Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)
2. The new Meta SO chat adds a (*) to the front of the title. This is somewhat reminiscent of IDEs which stick an asterisks to help inform user of unsaved files
3. If the messages are important *and* time sensitive (eg. chat) you might want to play a small sound to alert the user of new messages

These method would, of course, taking some getting used to, although it would certainly be less intrusive than constantly changing title.