# Is it possible change favicon on site when users change themes?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two themes on my site: Red, and Blue. This works fine.

I must know if I can make something to change the favicon, when users change the theme.

I know this code is for implementing favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

What do I need to make this possible? Using jQuery?

---

I have this script which I use for changing themes:

```
$("#painel_faccao li a").click(function() { 
        $("link#faccao").attr("href",$(this).attr('rel'));      
        $.cookie("css",$(this).attr('rel'), {expires: 365, path: '/'});
     return false;
     
  });
```

How I can implement this here?

(This question has a more modern approach to this function)

Comment: just change the href to different file

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is an answer on here on Stack Overflow: [Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)

I like this answer best:

If you have the following HTML snippet:

```
<link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
```

You can change the favicon using Javascript by changing the HREF element on this link, for instance (assuming you're using JQuery):

```
$("#favicon").attr("href","favicon2.png");
```

Just use JQuery to check the stylesheet and change the favicon based on it.

Comment: In some cases you need remove first favicon $('#favicon").remove(); and then add $('<link id="favicon" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="fav.ico" />').appendTo('head');

Comment: does this have any effect in ie?

Comment: The favicon changes in firebug html but did not reflect on browser. What is the issue ?

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, there is another way. Just do it

1. Remove **`<link rel="shortcut icon" ...>`**
2. Add the code below

> ```
> $(window).load(function () {
>     $('head').append('<link href="your_favicon_name.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />');
>   });
> ```

Comment: you answer is a little bit vage as you failed to explain what it does and why it is the best possible solution. cheers :)