# How can I change a favicon using jQuery when it doesn't have an ID?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I change a favicon using jQuery when it doesn't have an ID? I tried to add an ID, but I just can't seem to find it. I've been trying to get the right path in the Console without success. This is what I have tried: jQuery(:contains("shortcut icon")).attr("id", "favicon")

I figure these are the steps, but I haven't been able to get past the first one:

1. ACCESS LOCATION OF FAVICON VIA jQUERY: STUCK. Here's the HTML:

   ```
   <link href='/favicon.png' rel='shortcut icon' />
   ```
2. ADD AN ID TO THE FAVICON:

   ```
   $('element').attr('id', 'favicon');
   ```
3. USING THE ID, CHANGE FAVICON:

   ```
   $('#favicon').attr('href','https://aerohive.com/sites/all/themes/aerohivenetworks/favicon.ico');
   ```

This is the page: http://community.aerohive.com/aerohive

Comment: have you tried `$("link[rel='shortcut icon']").attr('href','your value')`

Comment: @Peter I wonder why do you suggest not to modify anything in head?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of the element is `link` not `element`.

You probably have multiple link elements though, so you should be more specific and use an attribute selector (since you have an attribute with a, presumably, unique value on it).

```
jQuery('link[rel="shortcut icon"]')
```

There is not point in adding an ID, throwing away your reference to the element, then getting a new reference to the element using the ID. Just skip step 2.

```
jQuery('link[rel="shortcut icon"]').attr('href','https://aerohive.com/sites/all/themes/aerohivenetworks/favicon.ico');
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer worked for me is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875689/is-it-possible-change-favicon-on-site-when-users-change-themes)

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('head').append('<link href="your_favicon_name.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />');
  });
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875689/is-it-possible-change-favicon-on-site-when-users-change-themes)