# Change favicon from Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, favicon

Is it possible to change the Favicon from Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the Favicon using JavaScript:

[Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)

Injecting JavaScript into the web page from Silverlight:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2008/12/04/silverlight-tip-how-to-inject-and-execute-javascript-function-s-on-the-fly-from-silverlight.aspx