# The best way to change favicon in browser

Tags: javascript, user-experience, favicon, visual-effects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)

How is it possible to create a loading effect on tab (favicon) in gmail way. When I click something which needs use AJAX, gmail shows a nice loading circle in tab or title bar of the browser. I know that I can change favicon but all my tries end in ugly way - sometimes it is working, sometimes not. Sometimes favicon doesn't change, sometimes it changes once and later changes are not applied. What is the best way to do that?