# Dynamic favicon using image manipulation similar to Gmail adding a count

Tags: javascript, canvas, dynamic, favicon

I tried to figure it out looking at the source code but I couldn't figure it out.

I would like to know how to make a dynamic favicon with a count like Gmail does.

[image]

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Note that Chrome's dynamic favicon implementation is buggy and uses too much CPU. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121333

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can make an image with the `canvas` element, and then just replace the current favicon. Check out the following link for a good explanation on it.
**[Reference](http://remysharp.com/2010/08/24/dynamic-favicons/)**

Code is from the above reference.

**Markup**

```
<link id="favicon" rel="icon" type="image/png" href="image.png" />
```

**JS**

```
  (function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx,
        img = document.createElement('img'),
        link = document.getElementById('favicon').cloneNode(true),
        day = (new Date).getDate() + '';
    
    if (canvas.getContext) {
      canvas.height = canvas.width = 16; // set the size
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      img.onload = function () { // once the image has loaded
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        ctx.font = 'bold 10px "helvetica", sans-serif';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#F0EEDD';
        if (day.length == 1) day = '0' + day;
        ctx.fillText(day, 2, 12);
        link.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
      };
      img.src = 'image.png';
    }
    
    })();
```

**Edit**

Must have an image set as well.

Comment: This code does more than stated in the first sentence. It is actually drawing on top of "image.png" (the template image source given in the script, not the default in `<link>`) after it is loaded and if the canvas context is available. Also, it is adding a [`<link>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) element to the body of the document (where it is illegal: `<head>` only), every time the function is run (in this case, once). So I'd try to omit the `cloneNode()` and `appendChild()` and only update the original link href.

Comment: document.getElementById('favicon').href = 
      canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

?