# Google Calendar favicon

Tags: javascript, html, css

does anyone have an idea, how the [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com) favicon works? It displays the current date now and not only a static image. I can't really believe, that they generated 31 icons and just used different icons per day. There must be a function I'm missing right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296574/dynamic-favicon-using-image-manipulation-similar-to-gmail-adding-a-count

Comment: Sometimes you are just searching for the wrong keywords.. Thanks!