# Can we control the "loading" icon in the browser tab?

Tags: jquery, browser

I have a series of AJAX calls via jQuery.  When an ajax call is being performed, there is no visual indication.  Normally if you click a link or otherwise some non-ajax load the browser displays a little loading icon up in the tab.

Is there any way to tell the browser to display this little icon in the tab?  (There are about 30 of these calls so I hope to avoid modifying each one).

Comment: The duplicate noted here was asked ~7 years ago.  This question was asked ~12 years ago.  Doesn't that make this duplicate closure backwards?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't tell the browser such a thing.

But you can do your own loading indicator. Include a hidden element in your markup, then use the [`ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`ajaxStop`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) events to control its visibility:

```
$("#loading_animation").bind({
    ajaxStart: function() { $(this).show(); },
    ajaxStop: function() { $(this).hide(); }
});
```

`ajaxStart` is fired by jQuery when an ajax request is started when none others are running; `ajaxStop` is fired when an ajax request completes are there are no others running.

Answer (score 9):

No.

But you can modify the css of the cursor.

```
body {
   cursor:wait;
}
```

Comment: I've explored a cursor change, but in my research the solution comes with a set of problems.  E.G. The loading icon is specific to elements on the page.  So to do a full page loading I need to add a wrapper div around the body, but this can cause freaky click break issues with Firefox.  If it comes down to it, I think I'd rather add a "loading..." popup.

Comment: A great non-intrusive loading indicator!

Answer (score 4):

Before getting into any code or anything I just want to say that this is a ugly solution, but it did actually work for me.

What I did was putting a iframe on the site. Then I hide it with *display: none* in the css.

Then on every ajax call I reload the iframe with a new page. This causes the browser to display the loading in the tab bar.

I do know it's not a pretty solution and it has some flaws. Like you can't control the duration of the loading if the iframe happens to load faster than the ajax. But I'm just throwing it out there. Maybe someone else can build on the concept.

Comment: This is not only ugly, it is a very bad idea; it will cause even more confusion (because it will *never* be accurate) and it causes needless bandwidth usage, browser memory usage, and server processing.

Comment: I agree with you. It's not a good idea, but it's an idea at least.

Comment: @AndrewBarber you can MAKE it accurate. have 1 forceLoadingBarIframe.php which basically does `$_SESSION['stop_loading']=false;while(!$_SESSION['stop_loading']){echo ' ';flush();sleep(1);}`  , then a stopLoadingBarIframe.php which basically does `$_SESSION['stop_loading']=true;`  - then fire a xhr request to stopLoadingBarIframe.php to stop the loading bar! with a fast connection, the loading bar should be just about 1 second off

Comment: You definitely *can* control the duration. On the server, just wait indefinitely in the request and don't close the connection. On the client, when you want the loading animation to end, just remove that iframe.

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely can. See this post: [Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)

Just create an animated icon of a loading graphic and change the icon to that while it's loading.

The problem will be that you don't have the exact same loading graphic as the particular browser uses, but I think the message will be effectively conveyed.

Comment: Favicon is not the same thing. No two browsers handle this alike. Not even the  same browsers/different versions.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Google's Chrome and Mozilla's Firefox are 2 different browsers, in fact, 2 very popular browsers, and they handle this pretty much the same way. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative.
Before making the call, you could show the image and then in the function (not after call) hide it again.