# Is it possible to trigger the browser's tab loading animation (spinner) with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, loading

In SPA/AJAX websites, when navigating between pages, only the modified parts of the page are fetched. These parts then replace the old ones in-place, within the same page. Because of this, the browser's built-in loading indicator – which is shown on page loads – is no triggered. Many websites incorporate a custom progress bar (like this one https://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/) to make it clear that a fetch is occurring.
I was wondering if there was any way at all to use the built-in browser's indicator instead (for example, the "tab spinner" in Chrome).

Comment: There is no reliable solution for this, but there are a few workarounds discussed here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139009/can-we-control-the-loading-icon-in-the-browser-tab