# How to change the icon in the head to "loading" during an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have realised that Facebook does that, don't know if any other webpage too. i wanted to know if it was possible using jquery, I have used common loading gifs previously while doing an ajax call but i figure this would be a nice touch. I appreciate your help

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Here's the procedure to change it:

HTML for your favicon in HEAD:

```
<link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
```

You can change the favicon using Javascript by changing the HREF element on this link, for instance (assuming you're using JQuery):

```
$("#favicon").attr("href","favicon2.png");
```

Comment: I think he is talking about the "favicon"-icon which is shown most likely in a browser-window or tab, not an ordinary image.

Comment: yes, i am aware of the common procedure to do that. what i was wondering was if it is possible to change the icon in the "title" of the page, in order to make it look as it was loading a whole new page. Facebook does something like that, i guess it does it throug javascript, i wondered if anyone knew how to. thanks regardless

Answer (score 1):

The *favicon* is either transfered automatically by a server HTTP application (just shipping a file called "favicon.ico" which has to be in a specific location) or you can explicitly require it by creating a `<link>` element.

For instance

```
<link type="image/x-icon" href="http://server.com/path/name.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
```

So, of course we can create that programatically too! Using jQuery:

```
var favIcon = $('<link>', {
    type:    'image/x-icon',
    rel:     'shortcut icon',
    href:    'http://servername.com/path/name.ico'
}).appendTo( document.head || document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[ 0 ] );
```

Now with that basic knowledge, we could switch *favicons* by removing and creating those `<link>` elements. So we could just call `favIcon.remove()` and create another one.

Comment: i guess I could change the favicon to another while the page is loading, but is there any way for the browser to show the same image it shows while a webpage is loading?