# Facebooks Notification Icon In The Windows Taskbar

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, web, icons

I'm wonderin how to realize a changing notification-icon in the windows 7 taskbar like facebook has one.

So if you have a notification on facebook, the ( docked ) Internet Explorer icon

[image]

is changing to

[image]

but the actual web icon stays the same ->

[image]

Do you know how this is happening and how to do this ?

**EDIT**

Please keep in mind that this question is not about just changing the website icon.

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically

Comment: as i said, the MAIN website icon is not changing... only the icon in the windows taskbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a built in feature in Internet Explorer, and it's called pinned sites.

The feature that you're specifically looking for is called "Pinned site notifications" and can be implemented through a simple meta-tag.

```
<meta name="msapplication-badge" content="frequency=30; polling-uri=http://mysite.com/id45453245/polling.xml"/>
```

The frequency is optional and is the time in minutes.

For a complete guide for what you should do, read through Microsoft's documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491731(v=vs.85).aspx

There's a lot of functions that can be implemented for pinned sites.