# Is it possible to stop browsers from caching favicon.ico?

Tags: php, caching, nginx, icons, favicon

I have `/favicon.ico` aliased to a PHP script that randomly chooses one of several icons every time it is accessed, by returning a `Location` header to the location of the chosen icon.

However, I want a (potentially) different icon to be shown each time, though Chrome (only browser I've tested) appears to cache the icon for quite some time. I have added these headers to both the `favicon.ico` redirection and the PNG icon files themselves, however, the icon still gets cached by the browser.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

I am using nginx. Is there any way to force the browser to refresh the icon every visit? Using the `<link>` tag in HTML is not an option for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically
https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/428626

Comment: i use the faviocon on the tab and bookmarks to identify a site, changing it frequently seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @user790454 see last line in question

Comment: @user790454 What do you mean by "Using the <link> tag in HTML is not an option for me"? You can't use a <link> tag at all? Why is that? There is a quite simple solution to your problem using a <link> tag, this is why I'm asking.

Comment: @philippe_b bro you've mis-tagged me,instead of OP :D

Comment: Damn! Sorry for the mistake... @user1814016, my previous comment was for you!

Comment: As of 2020, this caching behavior is still happening in Chrome. I've filed a bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1132138