# Different Favicon onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, favicon

I'm trying to find away to load a different favicon on page refresh/load. I've had a quick google but noting seems to be showing up in terms of tutorials.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/260857/362536

Comment: im a bit of a noob with jquery. which part of the approved answer do I add the additional icons?

Comment: All the code in that answer is for changing the icon.  I'm not sure what else you are asking.

Comment: Copy the code of the best answer and just replace link.href with the URL of the favicon you want...

Comment: Let's say I have 20 icons in my image folder is it a matter of pointing the href to that folder? Then it will pull a different icon out on load??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the answer from here: [Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)
I created what you want.

```
(function() {
    var arrFavicon = ['link_favicon1', 'link_favicon2', 'link_favicon3']; //put your favicon links here

    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/x-icon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    link.href = arrFavicon[Math.floor(Math.random()*arrFavicon.length)]; //don't need to change here no matter how many favicons you have
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}());
```

Now, all you have to do is put your favicons links inside the array  arrFavicon and will automatically generate diferents favicons every time that the page is loaded.

Comment: thanks. does this require me hosting the favicons on a url or will it pull them from my img folder?

Comment: You can use var arrFavicon = ['img/favicon1.ico', 'img/favicon2.ico'] ... got the idea?