# How to have default loading favicon come out on jquery .post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, .post

I'm looking to add default loading favicons to my site while its launching .post requests to another script.

I know that i can use ajaxform for the result that i'm looking for but that will require me to download an external script to my server.

I was wondering if there is an easier way of doing so and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you surely talking about [favicons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)?

Comment: Ya. When pages loads normally from one page to the other. The round blue circle beside the page title. Or is there another name to it? Please enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically

Comment: Yes. I saw that but i'm looking to have the default one coming up as animated favicons only work with firefox and i was wondering if i could get the default page loading favicon to appear. That was why i created this question.

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t help you with ready-to-go solution, while you might find this link helpful: http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/jQuery-Animated-Favicon-Notification-Plugin-Notify-Better.html