# Overriding a Favicon and Title without having access to the entire html/css sheets

Tags: html, css

I am working with a money management online portal that allows for customization of the login page, but doesnt allow submitting a full sheet of code. I have zero access to the header portion of the code. I am wondering if there is a way to override their title and favicon and replace it with my company's instead. Their company blocks javascript from being entered, as well, so it would have to be something I could write in html or css. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can't add a fav icon thru CSS, but if you could edit/insert some html that contained the appropriate tag that should work. You should be able to just drop the icon into the root and the browser should detect it.

Answer (score 0):

use the js, check this

```
(function() {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/x-icon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    link.href = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}());
```

[Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)

Comment: Not working for me, but thanks so much for the link!