# How can I customize a web app icon according to the app status?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, web-applications, iphone-web-app

I have a simple question regarding a feature that I would like to add to my web app.

Is it possible to change the app background (basically changing the favicon itself) according to an event happened in the app?

For example, if I want my webapp icon (installed on iphone or android using trigger.io) to have a green background if available or a red if not available, where should I start looking?

My only thought was to change, using javascript, the meta tag that sets the icon once the app is installed, but i don't think it will work because of the way mobile devices handles the "background apps"...

Really I don't know where to start searching for...

any ideas anyone?

thanks in advance

Comment: Well the favicon and the app icon for mobile systems are two different things (right?).  [Here is an old question about the favicon.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)

Comment: You are likely going to run into issues because of caching the image on remote side, which in my experience seems to be outside developer control.

Comment: Ok thank you guys. Appreciate your comments.
Have a great day