# Change Favicon on Tab Change

Tags: html, favicon

I'd like to change my favicon and browser tab text when a user navigates away to another browser tab. Does anyone know of a simple way to do this?

Comment: Don't cache that value and redegine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `window.onblur` event to change `document.title` and the favicon.  Changing favicons in some browsers can be tricky.  See [stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically/260876#260876](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically/260876%23260876) for more info.

```
window.onblur=function(){
    //change favicon
    document.title="bye";
}
window.onfocus=function(){
    document.title="hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to use javascript to detect if the tab is active:

[How to tell if browser/tab is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active)

Start with this next line in your `<head></head>`

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" id="changingFavicon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
```

Using the javascript example linked above to check if the tab is no longer active change the href to the new directory location like so using jquery.

```
$("#changingFavicon").attr("href", "http://newlocation.com/favicon.png");
```