# Detecting support for favicon hotswitching

Tags: javascript, html, favicon

So I've added some code that gets the count of notifications for the user and adds it in a little bubble to the favicon.

This is awesome.

But, as always, browsers don't always support it. This sucks.

I'd like to provide "[3] Page Title" as a fallback for such browsers, however I can't seem to detect when to apply this fallback.

Obviously browsers that don't support `<canvas>` are easily excluded, but it seems that setting the `href` of the new favicon works just fine, it just isn't applied. Any way to detect this behaviour?

Comment: Maybe this discussion may provide some insights http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically

Comment: @jornare I found that question, but that's all about doing the thing in the first place. Whether I update the existing `<link>` or replace it with a new one, the DOM accepts it but the browser may not.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://github.com/ejci/favico.js . The project is active so it may have a state of the art support checking.

Comment: Looks like it just excludes IE through a conditional comment and leaves it at that.