# Favicon Dynamic Code with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, favicon

The dynamic html code listed below:

```
<link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon/favicon.ico" />
$("#favicon").attr("href","./favicon2/favicon2.ico");
```

Does not switch between two favicon image files on clicking of the browser tab.

View attached screenshot image for details.

Q: What is the correct code?

[Background does not switch to the gray favicon image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vFZ2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the old Favicon link and then adding a new one with the new image

I havent tested the code but there is already a post on Stackoverflow on this: [Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)

Comment: There are two favicon image files, e.g., gray background and white background:                                                                                              <link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon/favicon.ico" />

$("#favicon").attr("href","./favicon2/favicon2.ico");