# Automate favicon.ico change in website in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to make field in the setting section of the web site that will help users to change favicon of the web site.

Comment: Can someone help, by giving some ideas how to do it?

Comment: Here given your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically