# How to display unread count in a webbrowsers pinned tab (own application)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

What is the best way to get an unread count for a pinned tab? I've my own application that should display an unread count when pinned. Can this only be done by using multiple fav icons? A browser extension is NO solution. Currently the unread count is only visible via document.title.

I've tried to use multiple favicons and change it at runtime. The problem is, that the browser seems to cache the favicon and never loads the changed one. Sometimes this works, but not in every browser. The problem is, that I'll need at least 100 favicons to reflect up to 100 unread items. But that's not really dynamic. May be there is a modern way to write a number to the icon dynamically?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that's not using hundrets of favicons. May be there is a modern API to accomplish this task.

Comment: I hope I've added more clarification to my question.

Comment: if caching and having 100 different icons is the problem, i don't know how it can be solved with javascript, but it can be solved with PHP.. is PHP an option?

Comment: http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/

Comment: @Ryan89: That was exactly what I was looking for. I really don't know why I'm getting downvotes for my valid question. I will mark your answer as accepted, if you want to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Favico.js](http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/) is a script that will allow you to add a notification to your favicon and update it whenever you need.