# How to add title and favicon in meteor 1.3 (iron router)

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

How to add title and favicon in meteor 1.3, using iron router and blaze ?

Comment: Take a look on [iron-router-title](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-iron-router-title) lib. This lib will let you set title per-router and reactively update it. For favicon use tag inside `<head>`

Answer (score 3):

In js you can set the page title anytime with:

```
document.title = "Foo";
```

This is much more flexible than including a static title in the `<head>` section as you generally want the title to change on a route-by-route basis.

In i-r you can do this in an [onAfterAction hook](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#available-hook-methods) ex:

```
onAfterAction() {
  document.title = 'mySiteName:' + Router.current().route.getName();
}
```

The icon can also be set dynamically, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

In the default layout template of iron router add the following lines in the starting of the html file.

`<head> 
   <link rel='icon' sizes="16x16 32x32" href='/favicon.ico' >
</head>`

Save the `/favicon.ico` in public directory in the meteor root app. Don't forget the `/` in `/favicon.ico`

Answer (score 1):

For favicon, add the following code in your main.html page in the head tag

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='favicon.ico' />
```

For title per page, you can add in each html template the following code

```
{{documentTitle 'Document Title'}}
```

And add the following code in a js file

```
//global template helper

Template.registerHelper('documentTitle', function(title){
    document.title = title;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use head tag inside the client/main.html file.

This will allow you to add title and favicon icon.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>MY Title</title>
  <link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/ >
</head>
```