# How to update favicon live without Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, favicon

I've been asked to make a favicon that updates to a new image when a process finishes in our app.  I've also been asked to avoid Javascript if possible.  Is this possible?  I feel like I'd need to use Javascript to change the favicon.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically

Comment: @Hespen I was also going to refer to that link. But Thomas is asking for non-javascript solution. That's impossible :)

Comment: You don't, unless you're okay with using Javascript.

Comment: You *could* do redirects/refreshes in intervals using hacky half-supported HTTP headers or HTML meta tags and update the favicon server-side… but that's an extremely yucky solution. If you want to do it *nicely*, there's no way around Javascript.

Comment: Define "when a process finishes" — What process? On the server? On the client?

Answer (score -3):

You can use any server-side language and an API such as http://realfavicongenerator.net/api

I use the non-interactive API w/ an ajax call on a project, but it can totally be done w/o javascript by just submitting a form and deal with it on the server (I use PHP).

Comment: While it's not 100% clear, the question strongly implies that they want to change the favicon without reloading the page. You can't do that on the server.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't said at all in the question.  It said no JS. I didn't even get that impression that it was implied.