# Changing website favicon dynamically: how to when div wraps head

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, favicon

I've found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically) to change a favicon using the code in content.js (run_at: document_end) of my Chrome extension:

```
(function() {
    var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/x-icon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    link.href = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}());
```

The above works wonders.

The problem arises when wrapping the whole document in a div to later apply some necessary custom CSS.

```
<html>
  <div id="allContent">
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
  </div>
</html>
```

In this situation the first code above doesn't change the favicon. I've tried changing its last line to:

```
document.getElementById("allContent").getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Although the link gets inserted correctly (at the bottom of `<head>` inside `<div id="allContent">`) the favicon doesn't change.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: That is invalid html. You cannot wrap the `head` nor the `body` in a `div`.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to change the favicon while mantaining some custom CSS on the whole page - that's why I have a div wrapping head and body. If this is not possible with the current html structure (because as Gaby points out is invalid), I'll have to rethink the design.

Comment: I need the `div` so I can apply `background-image`, it won't work if I refer directly to  `html`. @wOxxOm

Comment: Why do you think it won't work with `html`? It works here. You may need to increase specificity via `!important` though.

Comment: I tried to apply `background-image` directly to `html` but it wasn't working because of **"web_accessible_resources"**. Now I got it to work. Many thanks for your questioning @wOxxOm, overall architechture of the extension has improved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div>` is not valid between `<html>` and `<head>`. The rendering engine will work around it, but expect odd side effects like the meta properties (like `<link rel="icon" ... >`) being unpredictable or ignored.

Comment: Just to confirm, is there any html element that would be valid between `<html>` and `<head>`? Perhaps `<span>`?

Comment: @quackkkk afraid not: [**Permitted content** One `<head>` element, followed by one `<body>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html)