# Change favicon dynamically based on browser

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to come up with a way to set my favicon to be animated / static based on the users browser. The two favicon icons being

```
<link rel="icon" href="animated_favicon.gif" type="image/gif" >
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

I can probably detect the outdated browsers with a

```
navigator.userAgent.indexOf(//unfitBrowswer);
```

But where should this code reside in the project to set the favicon? Should I create a services that all my components use or is there somewhere in main.ts or otherwise?

Slightly different than linked duplicate due to location in angular as opposed to a pure JS script that can be run on startup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of jquery in Angular to do this.
Once you get the browser configuration.
Call this method on ngOnInit in your App Component

```
    SetApplicationFavicon(id,basepath,icon)
     { 
          $("#"+id).attr("href", basepath+"/"+icon); 
     }
```

> Or you can even make use of Renderer 2 to change the attribute of the
>   href tag at runtime either will work

.

Comment: I would rather not use jquery unless I need to, I'll give that renderer 2 a check. I think that is probably the best solution

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.userAgent.indexOf(//unfitBrowswer);
```

use in main.js file
you need to use the js for that.... change the href attribute of the favicon link when you detect the version of the browser

Comment: Right, but where would the optimal place be in an angular project?