# <link> tag gets removed from index.hml in angular 2 | update favicon in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to update app favicon in my angular 2 app by creating `<link>` tag in index.html
by doing:

```
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link id="appFavicon" rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/teal.png"></link>
</head>
```

However, the transpiled DOM does not have my `link` tag.  It deletes the `<link>` row.

This causes error:

```
core.es5.js:1084 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
```

when I try to update, the favicon in the app when doing something like:

```
this._document.getElementById('appFavicon').setAttribute('href', 'assets/images/red.png');
```

my component constructor has :

```
@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: any)
```

I have tried by using closed and non closed link tags as well:

```
<link id="appFavicon" rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/teal.png">
```

and

```
<link id="appFavicon" rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/teal.png"/>
```

I also tried to create a link element in `onInit` method as well, and that also does not get added to DOM.

Please suggest how to add `<link>` to DOM, or some alternate methods to update favicon.

Comment: <link> tag is HTML5 introduced. Have you added your code into <!DOCTYPE html>?

Comment: @M3ghana Actually, the `link` element was around in HTML 2. It is an empty element however, so there should be no `</link>` in the HTML, just like the `meta` elements.

Comment: If the transpiler is removing it, as you suggest, we need to know more about your build process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)

Comment: @M3ghana, Yes I have added !DOCTYPE tag.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I am using gulp, with webpack for compiling. Anything specific that I should look at, in the build process ? The final rendered app does not have the link tag.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most optimal solution but I create a method to do this task:

```
private updateFavicon(pathToIcon: string) {
    let link: any = this._document.getElementById('appFavicon') || this._document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/png';
    link.rel = 'icon';
    link.href = pathToIcon;
    link.id = 'appFavicon';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}
```

I am just passing the relative path to the file to be updated as favicon.