# Chrome Changing Icon in the bookmarked item dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, push-notification, bookmarks

I noticed one interesting feature in slack.Consider you have bookmarked the slack website in the chrome. Now somebody messages you. Slack automatically changes the colour of bookmark icon even though slack is not opened in any tab. How is this possible to change the favicon in a bookmark when dom is not loaded.

Do somebody know any chrome/browser API that let us do this.

Comment: I think this has been answered here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically

Comment: but how to change it when you dont have side loaded in any of the tabs

Comment: One possible way I can think of is to serve the favicon using an API, whenever user opens a new tab chrome requests the api, and api serves image dynamically