# Show tab blue dot in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If an alert is shown or a pinned tab's title is changed, a blue dot appears next to the favicon like so [image: Tab preview]

Is there a way to trigger this behaviour, in an user non-intrusive way (So no title changes or showing alerts) AND having it work for unpinned tabs?

Comment: I'm pretty sure (correct me if I'm wrong) that this is achieved by changing the favicon. A bit like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/260857/3436942)

Comment: @jbutler483 It appears to be out of the borders of a favicon. I do not want to fake this behaviour but have it work natively.

Comment: Looking at Chromium's [source](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/views/tabs/tab.cc?q=tab.cc+package:%5Echromium$&dr=C&l=1257), they call it an indicator. The comment suggests `When the tab is pinned, we can show one of the two icons. Alert icon
    // is given priority over the favicon.`