# Document.icon for javascript?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Document.title represents the name of a tab in javascript. For example, javascript: a=prompt("Create a new name for the tab"); document.title=a; void(0)
lets you change the name of the tab. you're on temporarily if you type it into the google search bar 
(Be careful, when you paste it, the javascript: part won't copy so you'll have to type that in yourself.)
Is there anything like that for the icon of the tab? like the picture next to the title? I would like to be able to temporarily change that too.

Also, apparently my questions are bad. My last two questions got -4 and -6 respectively. If you would like to I'd love some constructive criticism!

Comment: The icon is controlled by the `<link rel="shortcut icon" />` tag. `document.querySelector('link[rel="shortcut icon"]')` if it exists (create/insert it if not) and change its `href`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

The icon next to the website's title is called the [*Favicon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).

To directly answer your question, there is nothing like `document.icon`. But I like the idea :)

Favicons come in many forms and sizes:

- `<link rel="shortcut icon">`
- `<link rel="apple-touch-icon">` (see [Apple’s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html))
- `<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed">`
- `<meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo">` (see [Microsoft docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn255024(v=vs.60)#msapplication-square150x150logo))

You can also use [FaviconKit](https://faviconkit.com/) (I’m the maker) and get e.g. Stackoverflow’s favicon like

https://api.faviconkit.com/stackoverflow.com/128

(replace `stackoverflow.com` and `128` with your own domain and required size).

In your bookmarklet you could do something like

```
document.icon = 'https://faviconkit.com/?url=' + document.URL
```

and then reference `document.icon` whenever you need it.