# Why am I getting [object HTMLImageElement] when I try to set my favicon?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I posted a question yesterday and I got a very helpful answer. See question here: [Vue - Set different favicon when browser online or offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56843315/vue-set-different-favicon-when-browser-online-or-offline)

It also contains the code.

In my rendered HTML, I am getting `<link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="[object HTMLImageElement]">` when I am suppose the get the link.

How can I get the real link? Please check the code in the link above.

Comment: If you have issues with the answer you were given on an already existing question that you asked yourself, then please handle the issue there, instead of creating am duplicate.

Comment: I was unable to comment there.

Comment: It's not enough to refer to another resource to make your question complete. A question should stand alone. If the other question is deleted/altered, this question will cease to make sense. If your code isn't working, present the non-working code in the question.

Comment: You should always be able to comment on answers to your own question, regardless of reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
link.href = status ? this.favicons.online.src : this.favicons.offline.src;
```

I guess, but this should be moved to the original question

Comment: Yh I would do that