# add/change favicon using js

Tags: javascript, favicon, bookmarklet

I am making a bookmarklet that will open a menu in which you can change the websites favicon and title, and have presets. I am fine with the title changing, but I don't know how to add a favicon. I'm attempting to do so without having to find the websites favicon, but adding a favicon element. I have tried the following:

```
javascript:$('head').append('<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href='https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/infinite_arrow_favicon_5.ico"/>');
```

This would be a bit of code that would supposedly change the favicon to the google drive symbol, but it doesn't work for me. how would I inject a favicon into a website without knowing the specific element class or id, but by inserting a whole new element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');
link.type = 'image/png';
link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
link.href = 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/infinite_arrow_favicon_5.ico';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked, but my png didn't.  I now realize I am using a relative path that doesn't make sense in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to **[faviconjs](http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/)**, which support image change, animations and notifications. Its homepage lets you check in a blink if this library might be useful to you or not.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I may have figured out the problem.  In the actual program, I am using a relative href.  That makes sense in the original tab but not the new one.  (Relative to what?)  I just need to straighten out the path.  Thanks!