# Inserting a favicon for a single page

Tags: favicon

Is there a way to set a favicon for an individual page? I have a site that has a “mini-site” within it for a particular event and I would like all the branding for that page to be unique to it.

Comment: The question is answered here: https://serverfault.com/questions/308299/how-to-set-a-favicon-ico-for-a-specific-virtual-host-on-nginx

Comment: If you want to do this dynamically - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically). Please post more information about the problem - what you tried and what issues were encountered.