# changing browser tap icon depended on if dark-mode is enabled or not

Tags: javascript

I´m not good at Javascript, but I am wondering how I can change the browser tab icon depending on tap color.
I have found this script:

```
 const darkModeMediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
  darkModeMediaQuery.addListener((e) => {
    const darkModeOn = e.matches;
    console.log(`Dark mode is ${darkModeOn ? ' on' : '☀️ off'}.`);
  });
```

I am wondering how I could transfer this to; if darkmode yes:

```
<link rel="icon" href="dark">
```

If darkmode off:

```
<link rel="icon" href="light">
```

Keep in mind my JS knowledge is none existing, probably easy, but I didn't manage to find out. Help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing from this answer [Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)

You could add this function to your JS

```js
/*!
 * Dynamically changing favicons with JavaScript
 * Works in all A-grade browsers except Safari and Internet Explorer
 * Demo: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/dynamic-favicons
 */

// HTML5™, baby! http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/document-head
document.head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

function changeFavicon(src) {
 var link = document.createElement('link'),
     oldLink = document.getElementById('dynamic-favicon');
 link.id = 'dynamic-favicon';
 link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
 link.href = src;
 if (oldLink) {
  document.head.removeChild(oldLink);
 }
 document.head.appendChild(link);
}
```

and then you can call this function only when dark mode is enabled like

```js
if (window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
    changeFavicon('http://www.google.com/favicon.ico');
}
```

---

If you wanted to simply add any element to the head in dark mode you could use mostly the same code

```js
document.head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

if (window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
    document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<link rel="icon" href="dark">');
} else {
    document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<link rel="icon" href="light">');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your CSS config I think it would be better to work with macro classes. In your body or site wrapper div you could set a class and change it accordingly with the mode.

Eg.:

```html
<div id='site' class="dark"> 
   ...
</div>
```

OR

```html
<div id='site' class="light"> 
   ...
</div>
```

Yours CSS should look like:

```css
.light .title {}
.light .box {}
.light .header {}
```

```css
.dark .title {}
.dark .box {}
.dark .header {}
```

The JS should look like:

```js
function toggleMode(mode) {
   const siteWrapper = document.getElementById('site');
   siteWrapper.classList.remove('light','dark');   
   siteWrapper.classList.add(mode);
}
```