# Is There a Bookmarklet That Can Change Tab Favacon

Tags: javascript, tabs, favicon, bookmarklet

Is there a bookmarklet that can change a tab favicon?  I have tried google, and github.  I know this may be really complicated, but is there a bookmarklet that can do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically make it a bookmarklet

Comment: it works! thanks. hearis the final result: `javascript:(function()%7Bvar link %3D document.querySelector("link%5Brel~%3D'icon'%5D")%3Bif (!link) %7Blink %3D document.createElement('link')%3Blink.rel %3D 'icon'%3Bdocument.getElementsByTagName('head')%5B0%5D.appendChild(link)%3B%7Dlink.href %3D prompt('favicon url%3F'%2C 'https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Ffavicon.ico')%7D)()`

Answer (score 0):

Her is the final result of my research based on this question:[Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically).

The final result is as follows:
`javascript:(function()%7Bvar link %3D document.querySelector("link%5Brel~%3D'icon'%5D")%3Bif (!link) %7Blink %3D document.createElement('link')%3Blink.rel %3D 'icon'%3Bdocument.getElementsByTagName('head')%5B0%5D.appendChild(link)%3B%7Dlink.href %3D prompt('favicon url%3F'%2C 'https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Ffavicon.ico')%7D)()`