# Fallback favicon

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

From internet I get to know that some browser pick first favicon to display and some pick last favicon , when multiple favicons are present.

My usecase is when first favicon is not available fallback to fallback favicon. So used something like this

```html
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="firstFavicon" />
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="fallbackFavicon" /> 
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="firstFavicon" />
```

But in one use case it is not picking firstFavicon in chrome,edge and safari.
firstFavicon is `.ico` file of size 256 * 256 , fallback favicon is `.ico` of size 48 * 48

Comment: Could you describe your use case? Why the first favicon might not be available?

Comment: the reason favicon not available beacuse i am creating that favicon at runtime .. <domain-root>/favicon.ico .  fallback icon will always be present there btw.

Comment: It would be more elegant to handle this situation server-side, by returning the "best" icon available (the one generated at runtime, of the default one). Yet, I understand this is not always possible or convenient.

About your solution: although it looks correct, it is brittle. You need to test it on all major browsers and OS. And that might change someday...

The solution I think of is to apply the default icon, and use JS to change it to the best one, only if available. Heavy, but should work. For example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically

Comment: yes to check where domain favicon present or not , I need to do GET request to verify which will increase latency of page :-(