# How to use a "dynamic" icon for firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, firefox-addon

im currently trying to implement a dynamic addon for my firefox addon.
I want to add a counter as is used by honey oder AddBlock [AddBlock Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shIPk.png)

I cant find any explanation on the MDN developer guidelines on how to achive this though...
I know that I can set a new icon using

```
browser.browserAction.setIcon({path: "/path/to/image"});
```

but that would require me to create an image for every instance and rescale the image
accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you need to add a script for that. This is rough example and resource [Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i already got that figured out. But that alone wont solve the problem of adding the counter. Espacially because the counter is not within the boundaries of the normal icon, but semes to be an extra layer ontop of the icon.