# Use a different favicon based on a percentage chance

Tags: javascript, html, favicon

I want to have a Website, that displays the normal Favicon in most of the time but sometimes (In a rare case) I want it to show a different Favicon. Let's say we have a 10% Chance. Then it should display the second Favicon once in 10 Page refreshes. Right now I just have the Favicon1.ico and Favicon2.ico. Right now I'm only able to use 1. `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="..\images\favicon.ico" sizes="32x32" />`. I assume that with JavaScript I could do something like that but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: This is about changing the <link>'s href, which in general means setting an element's attribute. This is very easy to do in JS. Google "js set attribute".

Answer (score 0):

Hi in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically) the subject of being able to change the favicon in a dynamic way is covered, it can serve as a guide, you will only need to create a function so that you assign the behavior you want, Greetings

Comment: It is a great help even tho it didn't cover the x-chance of being the other one part. Thankfully I found out how to do it.