# Changing website favicon dynamically without it being requested each time it is appended to the DOM

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a feature where if a user has unread messages and navigates away from the app in the current tab, the app would then blink with an indicator at an interval every 1000ms. So if the user has 4 unread messages and opens a new tab, in the previous tab that they were just on, they'd see:

```
App | Home
* New messages (4)
App | Home
* New messages (4)
App | Home
// and so on every 1000ms until they navigate back to the tab
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically) question and got it working as I want it to, but I noticed that each time I append the favicon to the document, it is re-requested in the Network tab.

Yes it's cached, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this without the favicon being requested every interval loop?